# I am trying to plot such a figure in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot a figure like this:

[image: my figure].

Unfortunately, I could plot everything alone, but can someone provide me with a workaround on how to achieve this (something like this) in a single figure?

Comment: @Suever this is not a duplicate, please check the other question where they plot subplots. It is not ''subplot'' !!. So I don't understand how this could be a duplicate?

Comment: Why does subplot not work for you?

Comment: @suever Please check the figure attachment. As far as I tried this cannot be achieved by a subplot environment.

Comment: You'll likely have to draw all of the axes lines manually if you want it

Comment: @suever I don't know how to do it. Could you provide me with an example, so that I could build upon that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround could be:

0 - you have to calculate 2 graphs set of coordinates x,y with some offsets in order to draw "fake" axis

1 - plot one of your graph

2 - use `hold on` after every step of plotting

3 - plot the other graphs and use `hold on`

4 - use `quiver` to draw the arrows

5 - use `text` to put the text in the right place (you have to do some tries)

change quiver and text behaviour if you want

Comment: @macroresk I shall try that